# Simple code of Manipulation not working

Tags: manipulate

Consider the following simple code:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Point[{First[phi], Last[phi]}]], {phi, {0, 0}, {2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

The expected behavior is to follow the location of the 2D slider. However, the point does not move even I move the slider! (The point is always in the center.)
[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try adding an explicit `PlotRange` option.

Comment: Or add `Axes->True` and you will see that the axes move to keep the point centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Point[{First[phi], Last[phi]}],
  PlotRange -> {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {0 - 2 Pi, 2 Pi}},
  Frame -> True],
 {phi, {0, 0}, {2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

[image]
[image]